# Custom action bar is overlapping other elements

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement a custom action bar in an activity. I have done so below, but am getting my custom action bar overlapped with another. I have attached the screen shot below.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     private TextView actionBarTitle;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();  

        View customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);


        actionBarTitle =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_text);
        actionBarTitle.setText("Action bar");
      }

}
```

Manifest:

```
     <application
       android:name="MyApplication"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
       android:requiredForAllUsers="false">          

       <activity android:name="MainActivity"    
               android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

   </application>
```

actionbar_layout.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionbar_icon"
            android:text="title" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">sample</string>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
 <resources>

        <!--
            Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
            by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
        -->
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!--
                Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
                res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
                backward-compatibility can go here.
            -->
        </style>

        <!-- Application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
            <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        </style>
     <style name="Dialog_No_Border">
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
        </style>

    </resources>
```

How can I remove the sample text and black background so that only the custom view is displayed?

[image]

Comment: how to remove sample text and blackcolour background ..so only custom view is displayed..

Comment: (sample ) text and black colour bar has to disapper and onlyvisible icon and actionbar text.....

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing in your screenshot is exactly what the specification says is supposed to happen. When you use a custom view in the action bar, it is placed in between where the app icon (if any) on the left side of the action bar and the action buttons (if any) on the right side of the action bar.

> Custom navigation views appear **between the application icon and any action buttons and may use any space available there**.

[ActionBar#setCustomView(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 0):

try to Extend from Activity class and use Actionbar.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
**actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);**
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView)     mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("your title here");
actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

It worked for me!by inflating custom actionbar! but make sure it doesn't hinder other layout or components.

ps : i have used this in one of my project and worked well,if you're going through any error/bug/suggestion correct me.